# Grouping spring logback slf4j loggers

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j, spring-logback

I am running a spring boot application. for logging purpose we have used spring logback.

there is spring-logback.xml file where we define log level more likely at package level.

is there a way to group logger (may be at feature level) and package names are not same as feature name , which can have common configuration. more like instead of changing each class log level of feature . changing log level at feature which changes log level of all linked/grouped loggers.

Answer (score 0):

Spring support grouping in configuration properties rather than in logback-spring.xml

for more info
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-groups